# MvvmCross MvxException "Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel" under the RELEASE configuration

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, release, mvvmcross

I'm developing Xamarin.Android application with MvvmCross.
Every time I start app under RELEASE configuration it crashes on start with the following error:

> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and
>   initialize ViewModel for type DroidApp.Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel
>   from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more
>   information

This app works absolutely fine under DEBUG configuration.
The issue begins to raise just after I updated my code to use MvvmCross 3.1

Full output with stacktrace is below:

> 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and
>   initialize ViewModel for type Pcl.Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel from
>   locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more
>   information 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModelLocator)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.ViewModelFromRequest
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.CreateViewModelFromIntent
>   (Android.Content.Intent,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle)  03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.Load
>   (Android.Content.Intent,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,System.Type)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.LoadViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions/<>c_*DisplayClass3.b*_1
>   ()  03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView,System.Func`1<Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel>)
>   <IL 0x00013, 0x00113> 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.IMvxAndroidView,Android.OS.Bundle) <IL
>   0x00073, 0x0031f> 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled
>   (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1)
>    03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   (wrapper delegate-invoke)
>   System.EventHandler`1<Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1>.invoke_void_*this*__object_TEventArgs
>   (object,Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
>   <0x00067> 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise<Android.OS.Bundle>
>   (System.EventHandler`1>,object,Android.OS.Bundle)
>   <0x000c3> 03-16 03:53:04.110 I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.Views.MvxEventSourceActivity.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle)  03-16 03:53:04.110
>   I/MonoDroid(  593): at MyApp.Droid.Common.MvxActivityBase.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle)  03-16 03:53:04.110
>   I/MonoDroid(  593): at MyApp.Droid.Views.MainView.OnCreate
>   (Android.OS.Bundle)  03-16 03:53:04.110
>   I/MonoDroid(  593): at
>   Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)  03-16 03:53:04.110
>   I/MonoDroid(  593): at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.e62191de-ee25-45fe-b902-796a741820a1 (intptr,intptr,intptr)  Unhandled Exception:
>
> Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and
>   initialize ViewModel for type Pcl.Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel from
>   locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more
>   information 03-16 03:53:07.080 E/mono-rt (  593): [ERROR] FATAL
>   UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxException:
>   Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type
>   Pcl.Core.ViewModels.MainViewModel from locator
>   MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check MvxTrace for more information 03-16
>   03:53:07.080 E/mono-rt (  593):   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle
>   savedState, IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00000] in
>   :0  03-16 03:53:07.080 E/mono-rt (  593):   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle
>   savedState) [0x00000] in :0  03-16 03:53:07.080
>   E/mono-rt (  593):   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.ViewModelFromRequest
>   (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest viewModelRequest,
>   IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in :0  03-16
>   03:53:07.080 E/mono-rt (  593):   at
>   Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxAndroidViewsContainer.CreateViewModelFromIntent
>   (Android.Content.Intent intent, IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] The
>   program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: What do you have in trace output?

Comment: I have just updated the questions and included complete output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the information provided, I have no idea what is causing this problem.

The exception you've listed is thrown on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxViewModelLoader.cs#L46

This can only occur if `MvxDefaultViewModelLocator` returns `false`.

When `MvxDefaultViewModelLocator` returns `false` it always logs a message explaining why - see 
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs#L31

To debug it I would:

- try looking at the trace or log output - including routing this output to something that works in Release mode.
- try adding an exception handler around your `base.OnCreate()` call in `MainView` to see if it explains the problem.
- try adding some trace and/or breakpoints to your `MainViewModel` constructor - does it get called?
- try searching here for other problems which happen only in Release in Xamarin and/or MvvmCross

Comment: it tuned out that error was raised in separate method during Init() stage of MvxViewModel. Debug point wasn't hit, additional info wasn't provided. I found it by disabling code part by part.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem but tip from Stuart helped to figure it out.

I have ContactsViewModel which uses ContactsService via IoC engine. My MainViewModel contains ContactsViewModel ('cause Im using tab bar, like in tutorial).

And I just tried to remove service call inside ContactsViewModel and everything is fine. I've catched the error inside ctor and it said "The operation couldn’t be completed. (ABAddressBookErrorDomain error 1.)", so it's my service's fault.

So if anybody hit this error, just know remember that confusing "TargetInvocationException" is thrown always when any exception occur in ctor (particularly).